# How to change color of multiple text objects at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text

How to change color of multiple text or vector objects at once in Adobe Photoshop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the text layers by clicking on multiple text layers while pressing (ctrl+shift)  and press " T " see the top bar for fonts and color , click on the color box and change it to what you need it will change the color of entire selected text layers, you can change the font too with the same method.

(make sure auto-select layer is switched off )

Comment: Let me know if it works , ping me if you need more help!

Comment: It works, thanks mate. Basically same method can be applied to shapes just replacing usage of "T" by using "U" instead and changing fill color from top.

Comment: Any suggestion to recolor multiple shape objects?

Comment: @Vnovak yeah do the same as i said for Text layers, press " U " instead of " T" and change the fill color. cheers , let me know if you need more help ! :)

Comment: @Mohsin, thx! always overseen what is on top..